# Allow data traffic on Cellular device Win10 C#

Tags: c#, windows, wwan

I'm trying to make in C # to allow the data traffic of the Cellular device (wwan) when the user clicks disable or when the windows starts letting it as "disabled"  (in case a problem) , however I can only enable / disable the device.(hardware) The problem is that when enabling the device, it will not necessarily connect if the user click "disable" the cell phone as shown in the image below.

Tried with, WMI `Win32_NetworkAdapter`

And also with the new class `MSFT_NetAdapter`

But on both I can only enable / disable the device. So if the customer accidentally clicked turned off, it doesn't automatically reconnect.

[image: Figure 1 Has the enabled device but the cellular option is disabled]

*Figure 1 Has the enabled device but the cellular option is disabled*

[image: Figure 2 What I want is enable and disable the cellular option like picture above.]

Figure 2 What I want is enable and disable the cellular option like picture above.

**NOTE**: I am in .net framework 4.8 because I am doing a service for Windows.

**NOTE¹**: I tried to use the Xamarin library which I know has the capacity for this, but without success.

**Resume:**

> How to enable cell phone traffic if the user has disabled it?

Tag: C #, C # Console

Comment: hope my answer will help you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft has made a description on how to connect a mobile connection:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/connect-your-device/mbb

and also released the code on github

https://github.com/ms-iot/iot-utilities/tree/master/MBBConnect

At least they invoke `netsh mbn connect interface=Mobilfunk connmode=name name=GUID` to connect the interface

To check state (enabled/disabled):

```
netsh mbn show radio interface=Mobilfunk
```

to enable:

```
netsh mbn set powerstate interface=Mobilfunk state=on
```

Answer (score 2):

If I got your question correct then you can try this as well, make a service to check for the bellow registry Key value and change it accordingly.

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WwanSvc\GroupPolicy

Dword:

DisableWwanAutoConnect

Set the value to 1

You can also refer [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-wwan-mobile-connection-how-to-disable/66f9e93a-3fdb-470f-bd49-c2813bef8567?auth=1&page=2)

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample on how to turn on / off the Wifi and Bluetooth, but not for Cellular connection: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/RadioManager

If you loop deeper, they are not available at the current version of Windows:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.radios.radiokind

> MobileBroadband   2   A mobile broadband radio.
>
> Note
>
> This value is defined for future use and is not currently available.